# control tizen app label size and formats with html tags while using C specific modifications

Tags: c, tizen, tizen-wearable-sdk

I want to make my label fonts be a particular size and use C language specific word exchanges. Like below:

```
/* Label*/
wid->label = elm_label_add(wid->conform);
evas_object_resize(wid->label, 200, 100);
evas_object_move(wid->label,  (w / 4)+115, (h / 2 )+100);
evas_object_color_set(wid->label, 50, 255, 150, 255);
evas_object_show(wid->label);
elm_object_text_set(wid->label, ("<font_size=30 >%s</font_size>","TestString"));
```

At the end line I want '%s' to be replaced by 'TestString' but can't control its size as it won't change its default size or html tags are not working doing this format. I don't know any other way to make it work as tutorials are too scarce for this.

How can I change the size of this label?

Answer (score 2):

It is a simple string manipulation issue.

To build a string using substitution, snprintf can be used:

```
char buf[100];
snprintf(buf, 100, "<font_size=30>%s</font_size>", "TestString");
object_text_set(wid->label, buf);
```

What You were trying to do in the code You've presented will not work as you expect. The expression `("<font_size=30 >%s</font_size>","TestString")` always evaluates to `"TestString"`, due to the comma operator being used in parentheses. The value of the expression `(a, b, c, ..., z)` is equal to the last element.